# Capistrano make a new ami after deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, capistrano, capistrano3

I have a multi-server deploy happening on AWS.

I have a requirement where after deploy I need to create a new AMI and update my autoscaling group to use this new AMI.

What is the best approach to do this using Capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

Using CodeDeploy directly might be your best bet. However, you can write a Capistrano task using the AWS SDK to do whatever you want (it's just Ruby).

Comment: Will CodeDeploy update the AMI and also set up the autoscaling process?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the specifics of CodeDeploy, I just have a similar setup at my company (done by others). My understanding is that codedeploy has an agent that runs on the EC2 instances and updates them, then newly started instances due to autoscaling know how to set themselves up with new code. If you want to bake the application into the AMI, I have no experience with that. If you want to pursue CodeDeploy, you probably should make a new SO question about that so you get better help. (Alternatively, Docker and ECS are great here, but that's not your question. :)

Comment: I went the shell script route and using CLI am able to create the AMI after deploy.